# Proving Boolean ring

Tags: ring-theory

Prove that a ring $R$ with identity is a Boolean ring if and only if $a(a+b)b=0$ for all $a,b\in R$.

$a(a+b)b=0$ for all $a,b\in R$ (given), then $a^{2}b+ab^{2}=0$. And since it is a Boolean ring so $a^{2}=a$ and $b^{2}=b$ so then $2ab=0$.

Now what shall I do? Please give me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply $a^2=a$, because you *must* first prove it holds.

Hint for the “if” part: apply the hypothesis with $b=-1$.

Hint for the “only if” part: suppose $a^2=a$ for all $a$; then $a(a+b)b=a^2b+ab^2=ab+ab$

Comment: Pls tell me clearly I didn't understand

Comment: @user432805 What, precisely, you did not understand? Did you try expanding $a(a-1)(-1)=0$?

Comment: I mean if b=-1then it is true bt for the other values what will happen?

Comment: @user432805 You get $-a^2+a=0$, for all $a$. Isn't this the definition of Boolean ring?

Comment: OK I understood this

Comment: @user432805 And for the converse, you surely already know that, in a Boolean ring, $2x=0$, for every $x$.